# Is there any Office Apps javascript API to open sharepoint word document in client application

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office-js, javascript-api-for-office

We are developing Word Addin using Office Apps,
**Need to open Sharepoint word document in clientside Word using document URL**
Is there any Office Apps javascript API to open sharepoint word document in client application

Answer (score 0):

When you say open, you mean to launch a new instance of the word client to open the document?
If so, then no, at the moment we don't have this capability.

What you can do today is to use the Microsoft Graph to access the document stored in SharePoint via REST, you can find more information on this here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/

Comment: Hello Philip, I looked at the graph documentation and did not find an endpoint pertaining to SharePoint.

Comment: @EasyE Take a look at http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_get and note the /drives, which allows you to access other drives including SharePoint document libraries.

Comment: You're basically saying that there's a way of retrieving the files correct? So you cannot open/load the document?

Comment: @Detilium correct, you can retrieve the contents of the file using the Graph APIs, but currently there is no way to open another application from within the Office Javascript APIs.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to open an office document from outside... not in the word online... Btw the graph api for sharepoint isnt good explained